# How to monitor active threads in varnishd?

Tags: varnish

how do you monitor running threads in varnishd in production?

We have configured varnishd to max threads = min threads = 1000.

We are monitoring the MAIN.threads and MAIN.threads_created metric, but these metrics does not say anything about which threads are actively running or in pool, as I know of.

I do find the information I am looking for using "varnishscoreboard".

Threads running/in pool: 2/21
Tasks waiting/in queue: 0/0

, and I guess I can run varnishscoreboard in an interval and grep for the info I am interested in, but are there any other options?

In advance grateful for responses.

Answer (score 0):

The `MAIN.threads` metric in `varnishstat` is the one you should monitor. This metric returns the active metrics.

The `thread_pools` runtime parameter which you can retrieve via `sudo varnishadm param.show thread_pools` defines the number of thread pools these threads live in. The default value is 2 and there is no reason to every alter this value.

The `thread_pool_min` runtime parameter returns the minimum number of threads that will be created. And of course the `thread_pool_max` value defines the upper limit.

If your `thread_pool_min` value is set to 500, knowing that there are 2 thread pools, it makes sense that your `MAIN.threads` value is set to 1000.

If the `MAIN.threads_limited` counter increases, it means the maximum thread value was reached x-amount of times.

The value of the `MAIN.thread_queue_len` is the number of sessions that are queued that are waiting for a new thread. This also means no new thread could be created.

The `varnishscoreboard` gives better insight in what each thread is doing, but this tool is part of the [Varnish Enterprise](https://www.varnish-software.com/products/varnish-enterprise/) solution suite.

Long story short:

- Know your min & max threads per pool values
- Assume there 2 thread pools
- Use `MAIN.threads` to see how many threads are currently in use
- Use other thread-related counters to identify a potential thread shortage
- Use this information to properly tune `thread_pools_min` & `thread_pool_max` values

Creating threads is resource intensive, having the right amount of threads waiting in the thread pools is going to make your Varnish server more responsive. Don't set `thead_pools_min` too low. Also know that each thread consumes some memory as well, setting the values too high, could eat away unnecessary amounts of RAM from your system.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. We have set max and min threads to the same value and to a high number. This makes us a little blind, because then we miss out on the number of threads in "active use", and we never hit the thread_queue_len or threads_limited. That is the reason for my question. Is it so that the sess_conn reflects the threads in use?

Comment: @Jonas it does not. Varnish has a variety of threads. It's actually the acceptor thread that is reponsible for handling sessions. The worker thread (which we're talking about here) do request handling, backend fetching and probe checking.